# Background Image on JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, background, javafx

I'm trying to put a background image on the GUI of a Java program I'm making.

I tried doing it by putting in the stylesheet of the Anchor Pane something like

```
#AnchorPane {
-fx-background-image: ("/capa.jpg");
}
```

Problem is, it says the image where it was pointed could not be found.

This is how the directories are located in my project.

project > source packages > package > capa.jpg

I've never done a program where I had to add an image to it before, so it might be a stupid mistake like putting it in the wrong folder.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#AnchorPane {
-fx-background-image: url("capa.jpg");
}
```